# Wordpress Archive.php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I made the archive.php to display FULL post but now i want to make it display only the latest post of each category. here is the code i already did for FULL post

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php topfit_mikado_get_title(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('slider'); ?>
        <div class="mkd-container">
            <?php topfit_mikado_image_title_featured_image(); ?>
            <div class="mkd-container-inner">
                <?php do_action('topfit_mikado_after_container_open'); ?>
                <?php topfit_mikado_get_blog_single(); ?>
                <?php do_action('topfit_mikado_before_container_close'); ?>
            </div>
            <?php topfit_mikado_get_single_post_navigation_template(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: put a `break;` in the loop at the bottom and you will just get the first item

Comment: break? where shall i put it exactly?

Comment: just befor endwhile

Comment: that worked. Thank you very much

Comment: I'll add an answer then if you'll upvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a loop. If you only need the first item from that loop, you can use `break` to come out of the loop early.

Just put it at the bottom before the endwhile :-)